# Homeomorphism vs bijective and continuous

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am trying to understand the difference between a function which is a homeomorphism and for example a function $f:U \rightarrow V$ (U, V open sets) which is bijective and strictly increasing . The last one should be continuous but I am not sure how to prove it.  Could anyone help me?

Thank you!

Comment: A *homomorphism* is usually a nice map between *algebraic* structures (such as groups). Do you mean *homeomorphism* (continuous bijection with continuous inverse)?

Comment: I was indeed talking about homeomorphism thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: I'm not sure if this can help, but (related to the title of the post) a classical example of continuous bijective function with discontinuous inverse is $e^{i\cdot}\colon [0,2\pi)\to S^1$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* The inverse image of $(a,b)\cap V$ is $\bigl(f^{-1}(a),f^{-1}(b)\bigr)\cap U$.

Comment: I see but why is that enough to conclude  that the image is open?

Answer (score 1):

If you understand the hint, then the rest should be clear.

Note: U and V are given the subspace topology from $\mathbb R$. So any open set of V will look like W$\cap$V, where W is an open set in $\mathbb R$and W can be written as union of intervals $(a,b)$ (the intervals forms a basis for the topology.)

$f^{-1}(\cup {(a,b)}\cap V)=\cup f^{-1}((a,b)\cap V)=\cup ( (f^{-1}(a),f^{-1}(b)\cap U)$

Is it clear now?